# Количество секунд с начала суток

Tags: c

Как можно получить количество секунд сначала суток в int?
Есть функция получающее количество секунд с начала 1970 года, но нужно количество от начала сегодняшнего дня в int.

Comment: Для начала нужно определиться — что такое начало суток? В каком часовом поясе? С учётом перехода на летнее время или без?

Comment: хм.. а считать системное время никак не получится?
без учета летнего времени, (UTC+03:00)

Comment: Если системное, то есть функция [localtime](http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/localtime.html), которая позволит получить часы, минуты и секунды и затем посчитать всё что надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество секунд в сутках это

```
int tsecint=24*60*60;
```

Соответственно, текущее количество секунд делите (как целое) на tsecint, получаете количество суток. Остаток от деления этих же величин это и есть количество секунд в текущих сутках. (Остаток от деления получите, применив операцию "%".)

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

time_t day_seconds() {
   time_t t1, t2;
   struct tm tms;
   time(&t1);
   localtime_r(&t1, &tms);
   tms.tm_hour = 0;
   tms.tm_min = 0;
   tms.tm_sec = 0;
   t2 = mktime(&tms);
   return t1 - t2;
}

int main() {
   printf("%d\n", (int)day_seconds());
   return 0;
}
```